# How to deploy Open Policy Agent in a Google Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, open-policy-agent

I'm new to k8s, and I want to deploy OPA in the same pod as of my application in Google Kubernetes engine. But I don't know how to do this.Are there any references that I can refer more details about this ? Could you please help me figure out the steps I should follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should similar as deploying to any Kubernetes cluster as documented [here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/deployments/#kubernetes). The difference could be you may want to use a LoadBalancer type service instead of NodePort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer .I will try it this way.