# Multiple containers within same pod on google kubernetes engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, open-policy-agent

I want to deploy OPA with my application as a side car container on google k8s engine.so need help to find out the steps I should follow and Are there any example blogs which I can find this out??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy Open Policy Agent in a Google Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258321/how-to-deploy-open-policy-agent-in-a-google-kubernetes-cluster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is a side car container. This is not specific to GKE and can be done on any k8s cluster. Your pod spec will include a list of containers (one for the main application and at least one sidecar) and will look something like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: <my_main_app>:v1.1.2
    name: myApp
  - image: <sidecar_container>:latest
    name: sidecar_app
```

Note that all the containers within the same pod share a network namespace so the containers cannot be assigned the same ports. Otherwise, feel free to add multiple containers to the pod (kube-dns is a good example of this)